# Serialize / Unserialize boolean data in PHP

Tags: php

I'm having some issues using the `serialize` and `unserialize` PHP function as it relates to boolean data.

If I `serialize` this array:

```
$test = [
   "id" => "test",
   "name" => "Test",
   "isActive" => 0
];

$data = serialize($test);
```

And then `unserialize` it:

```
$data = unserialize($data);
```

This is the array I am seeing:

```
$data = [
   "id" => "test",
   "name" => "Test",
   "isActive" => "0"
];
```

It has converted the boolean property to a string. Any ideas on how to keep that property in tact?

I read that `serialize` and `unserialize` do not recognize true/false.

Comment: What boolean? There is no boolean in your initial array, there's a number. (PHP has typing, and while it might coerce zero to false, they're _not_ the same type, trivially confirmed with `0 === false`). That said, which version of PHP? Because in every supported version this works fine, and generates the number 0, not the string "0".

Comment: From my understanding, `0` also represents false. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php#66147

Comment: This fiddle says it deserializes `isActive` as `0` (since it's `s:8:"isActive";i:0;`, with `i` standing for `integer`. https://3v4l.org/JsPVa

Comment: This shows it deserializing `true` as a boolean (`s:12:"isActiveBool";b:1;`): https://3v4l.org/47WTS

Comment: @JaredFarrish Interesting. I am going to explicitly try to set isActive with a bool flag: `$test = [
   "id" => "test",
   "name" => "Test",
   "isActive" => (bool) 0
];`

Comment: @zeropsi That's an incorrect reading of that comment. `s:12:"isActiveBool";b:1;` stores the _serialized_ boolean value as `0` or `1`, but deserializes as it's type.

Comment: @zeropsi You could just use `true` or `false`. PHP is truthy, so `0/1` are equivalent to false/true` without declaring strict types, but you can use actual boolean values instead of a number representation.

Comment: Every PHP version I've tested yields the original data when using `unserialize(serialize(["isActive" => 0]))`, so unless you have a [mcve], this is simply not reproducible.

Comment: No version of PHP has a version of `serialize()` or `unserialize` that will change the data like that. The problem is almost certainly in the data you're feeding to the initial serialize. https://3v4l.org/JsPVa

Comment: Also, `0` is not `false`. In a loose comparison `0` can be _type juggled_ to `false`.

Comment: Checking on the data that is being input to see if there is a data mismatch.

Comment: Maybe you want `unserialize($data)`.  Your current code gives _Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: unserialize(): Argument #1 ($data) must be of type string, array given_

Answer (score 0):

For unsialize you have to take $data as a parameter and not $test. Then Boolean variables are also reproduced exactly.

```
$test = [
   "string" => "test",
   "int" => 0,
   "isActive" => true,
   "bool" => false
];

$data = serialize($test);

$testRestored = unserialize($data); 

var_export($testRestored);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'string' => 'test',
  'int' => 0,
  'isActive' => true,
  'bool' => false,
)
```

The strict comparison === of the two arrays shows that the arrays $test and $testRestored have identical content.

```
var_dump($test === $testRestored); //bool(true)
```